# SSIS. Load the same data from web-service to different tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, etl, ssis-2012

I'm using SQL Server Data Tools 2015.
My task is download two different tables from some web service.
Also I download data from different objects to single dataset, generally there is no problems with another tables. 
But this two tables have the same column names. 
I use next code for second table:

```
foreach (XElement new_el in tmp2.Elements(new_ns + "Item"))
    {

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.newid                  =   new_el.Element(new_ns  +  "id"                  ).Value.ToString();
        Output0Buffer.newnameeng             =   new_el.Element(new_ns  +  "name_eng"            ).Value.ToString();
        Output0Buffer.newnamerus             =   new_el.Element(new_ns  +  "name_rus"            ).Value.ToString();
        Output0Buffer.newstatusesupdatetime  =   new_el.Element(new_ns  +  "statuses_update_time").Value.ToString();
    }
```

And next code for first table:

```
foreach (XElement el in tmp.Elements(ns + "Item"))
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.id            = el.Element(ns + "id"                  ).Value.ToString();
        Output0Buffer.NameRus       = el.Element(ns + "name_rus"            ).Value.ToString();
        Output0Buffer.NameEng       = el.Element(ns + "name_eng"            ).Value.ToString();
        Output0Buffer.statusid      = el.Element(ns + "statuses_id"         ).Value.ToString();
        Output0Buffer.updt          = el.Element(ns + "statuses_update_time").Value.ToString();
    }
```

Full code you can find here:
https://pastebin.com/X4WFcKaD
And here: /SBj9kwV7

As a result I have two different tables with same data on my SQL Server:

```
Idt NameEng Updt                Status_id
1   comm.   23.11.2010 18:40    NULL
2   pref.   23.11.2010 18:40    NULL
3           23.11.2010 18:47    NULL
4           15.08.2011 15:28    NULL
5           14.08.2012 17:46    NULL
6           14.08.2012 17:46    NULL
7           14.08.2012 17:46    NULL
```

I have the impression that I'm taking the same variables from the namespace. What could be the problem?

[the same data rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL8L8.png)